# Can you begin at the second, or other line, of a file when using ifstream in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

> 529.23
>   Jalopy Blue 3402.99
>   Rustbucket Brown 44.99
>  
>   Lemon Yellow 4226.99

The first number listed there, 529.23, will be put into a variable of its own. It will be the total "balance" in my program. The next items are the name, color and price of cars to be put into separate variables after. What I want to know is can I just read the first line and assign that to a variable (A string obviously, then change it to an integer)? Then, can I skip that first line (529.23) and start reading at "Jalopy" and go from there to assign those items to different variables? Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

(This is the first question I've asked on stackoverflow. So let me know how I can improve my "question asking". Thanks.)

Comment: Yes you can do that. There are a tremendous number of posts on SO that deal with reading data into variables, I suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: Use atoi(string.c_str()); to turn a string into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping a line is simply done by using `std::getline` and not using the result:

```
std::ifstream is("file.txt");
std::string line;
std::getline(is, line); // skipping line 1
std::getline(is, line); // skipping line 2
```

And don't forget error checking. For example, consider what happens when the file is empty, does not exist, has only one line etc...

Comment: That's pretty wasteful, especialy if lines are long. Why not `ifstream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`?

Comment: Simplicity. I think the ignore() approach is good when performance really is an issue, but the downside is that it adds more complexity and ways to introduce subtle errors (e.g. it's not a compiler error but only a warning -- at least in VC 2013 -- when you accidentally exchange the two arguments of the function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extractor for the first line:

```
double d;

if (file >> d)
{
    std::cout << d; // 529.23
}
```

For the other lines, you can also use the extractor. The following example puts data from the second line into variables:

```
std::string name, color;
double price;

if (file >> name >> color >> price)
{
    // ...
}
```